# Find all the possibilities of Rational Canonical Form if the characteristic polynomial is given?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that a linear transformation $T : \mathbb{R}^6 \to  \mathbb{R}^6$ has characteristic polynomial  $P_T(t) = (t^2 + 5)^2(t − 1)^2$.

(i) What are the possibilities for the minimal polynomial $M_T (t)$ of $T$ ?

(ii) What are the possibilities for the rational canonical form for $T$?

This is a question from a final that I'm not too sure on how to proceed.
I thought the the minimal polynomial would be one of the four,
$$
\begin{aligned}
 (t^2+5)(t-1)
\\(t^2+5)^2(t-1)
\\(t^2+5)(t-1)^2
\\(t^2+5)^2(t-1)^2
\end{aligned}
$$
but someone pointed out to me that the characteristic polynomial doesn't split completely.
Also I have no clue on how to proceed to find all the possibilities of RCF.

Comment: The idea is that a characteristic polynomial will have terms like $(x-a)^n$ with $n>1$ but the minimal polynomial will not count multiplicity. If you write your question better I will be able to provide a more exact answer.

Comment: Yes, we have been given the characteristic polynomial, and then asked to find the minimal polynomial and rational canonical form from it. I hope that is a more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The possible list of invariant factors is (the last entry in each list below is the minimal polynomial):

1. $\{(t^{2} + 5)(t-1), (t^{2} + 5)(t-1) \}$ --- giving two blocks each a $3 \times 3$ matrix and it is easy to write the companion matrices making up such blocks.
2. $\{(t^{2} + 5), (t^{2} + 5)(t-1)^{2} \}$ --- giving two blocks one a $ 2 \times 2$ matrix while the other a $4 \times 4$ matrix.
3. $\{(t-1), (t^{2} +5)^{2}(t-1) \}$.
4. $\{ (t^{2} + 5)^{2}(t-1)^{2}\}$ --- there is only one block as the minimal and characteristic are equal.

Comment: I'm don't know what you mean when you say,

{(t^2 + 5)(t - 1), (t^2 +5)(t - 1)}

Comment: oh never mind, just got what you meant!

Comment: I have a follow up, suppose the characteristic polynomial was (t^2 + 3)^2
then the possibilities for the minimal polynomial would be (t^2 + 3) or (t^2 + 3)^2, right?

Comment: Yes, that will be the correct possibilities.

Comment: Alright, Thanks !